# Program in Eclipse not Running

Tags: java, eclipse

I've just installed Eclipse 4.2.0 and also imported all my old programs into it, except that when I run my programs, it pops up with a message saying:

Select what to run:

Ant Build: Launches an Ant Build with default

Ant Build...: Launches an Ant Build and allows it to be configured

[image]

This message has never appeared to me before. I wonder if it is because I imported my files incorrectly or something that I forgot to install. Please tell me how I can make it work properly again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried simply creating a new "Run" configuration?

Comment: You most likely need to configure it to run with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! this is an issue I've experienced earlier. This tip solved the issue. Here's How to do it.

Make sure that you've built it. Or you can enable `Project --> Build Automatically`.

After the above option is set, try cleaning the workspace. `Project --> Clean` and clean all the projects you've imported.

Now `restart` eclipse and you can launch your program.