# Can't run a thread in Java using exception

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, primes

Amended a program on prime number using exception but it couldn't be run in Eclipse.  Why?

```
public class PrimeThreads {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        PrimeThreads pt = new PrimeThreads(arguments);
    }

    public PrimeThreads(String[] arguments) {
        PrimeFinder[] finder = new PrimeFinder[arguments.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            try {
                long count = Long.parseLong(arguments[i]);
                finder[i] = new PrimeFinder(count);
                System.out.println("Looking for prime " + count);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + nfe.getMessage());
            } catch (NegativeNumberException nne) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + nne.getMessage());
            }
        }
        boolean complete = false;
        while (!complete) {
            complete = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < finder.length; j++) {
                if (finder[j] == null) continue;
                if (!finder[j].finished) {
                    complete = false;
                } else {
                    displayResult(finder[j]);
                    finder[j] = null;
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayResult(PrimeFinder finder) {
        System.out.println("Prime " + finder.target
            + " is " + finder.prime);
    }
}
```

After run, it seemed nothing happened in output screen, it supposed not to be. OMG!

Here is code for PrimeFinder:

```
public class PrimeFinder implements Runnable{
    public long target;
    public long prime;
    public boolean finished = false;
    private Thread runner;

    PrimeFinder(long inTarget) throws NegativeNumberException {
        if (inTarget < 0) {
            NegativeNumberException nne = new NegativeNumberException("Negative numbers not allowed: " + inTarget);
            throw nne;
        }
        target = inTarget;
        if (runner == null) {
            runner = new Thread(this);
            runner.start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        long numPrimes = 0;
        long candidate = 2;

        while (numPrimes < target) {
            if (isPrime(candidate)) {
                numPrimes++;
                prime = candidate;
            }
            candidate++;
        }
        finished = true;
    }

    boolean isPrime(long checkNumber) {
        double root = Math.sqrt(checkNumber);
        for (int i = 2; i <=root; i++) {
            if (checkNumber % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;        
    }

    class NegativeNumberException extends Exception {
        NegativeNumberException() {
            super();
        }
        NegativeNumberException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: How did you run the program? Did you initialized the arguments in the Eclipse run profile?

Comment: use (>) run button.  After found not running properly, I amended the [run configurations]: [Project] & [Main class]

Comment: I tried to [clear the projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232446/program-in-eclipse-not-running)

Comment: could you please add the PrimeFinder class code?

Comment: unrelated to question but just wonder.... why not use `join()` instead of all those `finished` and loops?

Comment: and, if you are running in Eclipse, you can make sure it is running by debugging it.  And, how's the question related to "Exception"?  My personal advise is to make a program as simple as possible and make sure you know how to execute a java application in Eclipse first.

Comment: btw, your program does not compile, as `NegativeNumberException` is a inner class of `PrimeFinder`, but in `PrimeThreads`, the catch statement you are catching `NegativeNumberException` instead of `PrimeFinder.NegativeNumberException`, nor I can see you have related static import